# Mongoose create multiple indexes

Tags: mongodb, express, indexing, mongoose

I have one problem I wanted to implement full text search for mongodb, so i got stuck becouse in database created just one index for text search and i want to have multiple fields for search .. exmaple of schema :

```js
name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
    index: 'text'
  },
  sub_name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true

  },
  location: [{
      geo: {
        type: [Number],
        index: '2d'
      },
      description: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        index: 'text'
      },
      address: {

        city: {
          type: String,
          index: 'text'
        },

        street: {
          type: String,
          index: 'text'
        },
        state: {
          type: String,
          index: 'text'
        }
      },
```

so what is the trick to do that ? how can i apply mutliple fields for full text search  ? thx for anwser ...

Answer (score 7):

Try something like that:

```
var schema= new Schema({
  name: String,
  sub_name: String,
  tags: { type: [String], index: true } // field level
});

schema.index({ name: 'text', sub_name: 'text' }); // schema level
```

Comment: and how do i apply index  in description ? schema.index({ 'location.description': 'text', type: 'text' }); ?

Comment: I've never created index on nested fields in mongoose, but since that is the way you create index in mogno shell(by specifying the path) i guess thats how it should work in mongoose as well.  schemaObj.index({ 'location.description': 'text', type: 'text' });

Answer (score 0):

Create Multiple Text Indexes use this. this will help for full text search

1. FIND THE INDEXES : `db.collectionName.getIndexes();`
2. Than Drop index Name:  `db.campaigns.dropIndex('name_text');`
3. Create Indexes on Multiple Key: `db.campaigns.ensureIndex({ name: 'text' , description: 'text', tags : 'text' });`